# Pandas with regex

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe were there will be multiple values. I need to filter only values that match my condition.

For Example

df

```
col1
Tesla
Audi
BMW-N2204281200PE
SUPRA2204241300.75CE
TATA230612133.50PE
```

I need to filter only the values like the last 3 rows. It will be a string that will be starting with characters, may have symbols(-,&,$) followed by characters ,will have 6 digit value, then some price like 1300,1300.75, and ends with PE or CE

How could I do this using pandas?
Also how could I split the same symbol like `['BMW-N','220428',1200PE], ['SUPRA','220424','1300.75CE' ]` ?

Comment: how do you discriminates `TATA,230612,133.50PE` from `TATA2,306121,33.50PE`?

Comment: There won't be any number after the string, so a string that may have symbol(-,&,$) followed by 6 digit number, then some price and ends with PE or CE.....It will always be like [TATA,220612,133.50PE] and [BMW-N,220428,1200PE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
df['col1'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z-&$]+)(\d{6})(\d+(?:\.\d+)?[PC]E)')
```

output:

```
       0       1          2
0    NaN     NaN        NaN
1    NaN     NaN        NaN
2  BMW-N  220428     1200PE
3  SUPRA  220424  1300.75CE
4   TATA  230612   133.50PE
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rla0Qz/1)